# object` ("[object Response]") cannot be serialized as JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, fetch-api

I am trying to consume my api through code I am getting this error

**object` ("[object Response]") cannot be serialized as JSON**

But when I call or use this api through browser I am getting response.

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-platform-1xket?file=/pages/index.js

I am consuming my api like this

```
 console.log("-----");
  const cc = await fetch("https://1xket.sse.codesandbox.io/api/basecss/");
  console.log(cc, "llll");
```

**API design**

```
export default async (req, res) => {
  const stylesheet = await (
    await fetch("https://www.****.com/asset/web/css/***-base.css", {})
  ).text();
  console.log(stylesheet, "server");
  res.status(200).send(stylesheet);
};
```

I am getting this console value on server. but when I am calling this api through code I am getting this error

```
object` ("[object Response]") cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that error because you're returning a response object (`cc`) in your `getStaticProps` which is not serializable. [`getStaticProps` and `getServerSideProps` only allow serializable content to be returned](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/11993#issuecomment-617937409) from them.

To fix the issue you'll first need to convert the response data to text before you can return it. You'll also need to change your props to match the ones expected in the `IndexPage` component.

```js
// pages/index.js

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await fetch("https://1xket.sse.codesandbox.io/api/basecss/");
    const stylesheet = await res.text(); // Converts response data to text

    return {
        props: {
            stylesheet // Changes prop name from `cc` to `stylesheet` to match component
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

That is because `fetch` returns a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response), after the response is returned, you need to parse the response `response.json()` `response.text()` etc. This is also an asynchronous operation, and I believe that you can't nest `await` statements like that.

```js
  const response = await fetch("https://www.****.com/asset/web/css/***-base.css")
  const data = await response.text()
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this for Firestore types, specifically for geopoint and timestamp types was to use some method that transforms the non-serializeable property into one.

```js
CreatedAt: data.createdAt.toMillis(),
updatedAt: data.updatedAt.toMillis(),
coordinates: null,
latitude: Number(JSON.stringify(data?.coordinates?.latitude) ),
longitude: Number(JSON.stringify(data?.coordinates?.longitude)),
```

For Firestore timestamp objects, you can use the .toMillis() method.
For Firestore Geopoint objects, you can first turn the location(coordinate) into 'null' and then if you need the specific latitude and longitude properties, you can use the latitude and longitude properties to pull these out and then just cast them as "Numbers".